# Linux shell script to search logs with user input

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a script which searches a tomcat log from a keyword which the user inputs. I'm having issues getting the read command to work correctly.

```
#!/bin/bash

  TOM1=/ap/mvr/servers/tomcat1/logs/
  TOM2=/ap/mvr/servers/tomcat2/logs/

  find $TOM1 $TOM2 -type f -name "mvr-gateway.log" | while read file
  echo "What do you want to search for? " keyword
  read keyword
  do
     LOGERRORS=$(grep -B1 -A1 $keyword $file)
     if [[ ! -z $LOGERRORS ]]
     then
     echo $file
     else echo No Data Found
     fi
  done
```

Comment: Which issues do you have? Why it is not working as expected?

Comment: Ask the user *before* you start searching through the files

Comment: Thanks! It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

TOM1=/ap/mvr/servers/tomcat1/logs/
TOM2=/ap/mvr/servers/tomcat2/logs/

read  -p "What do you want to search for?" search_term

grep -B1 -A1 ${search_term} $(find $TOM1 $TOM2 -type f -name "mvr-gateway.log")
```

As mentioned before, ask first the term you are searching for.